# Python Add up numbers from 1 to N (WHILE LOOP) and keep adding

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to add up all the number from 1 to N and print the result and then keep asking the user to enter number till the number zero is entered. I can make it sum the numbers and end the while but can't make it keep asking for more numbers like this: https://pastebin.com/9pWDT6su

```
num = int(input('N: '))
sum = 0

while num != 0:
    while num < 0:
        num = int(input('ERROR - N: '))

    sum = sum + num
    num = num - 1

    print('Sum: ', sum) 
    # If I put this outside the WHILE it'll work but it won't allow me to
    # keep adding numbers  
    num = int(input('N: '))

print('END')
```

Comment: For instance, if number 5 is entered it should do  1+2+3+4+5  and then print 15 and then ask the to enter another number. Thanks

Comment: Nothing in your code looks like an `1->n` loop tho. Please add more details about what's not working. Also, instead of adding comments, please [edit] your question and add the details there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
num = int(input('N: '))

while num != 0:
    sum=0
    while num > 0:
        sum = sum + num
        num = num - 1
    
    print('Sum: ', sum)
    num = int(input('N: '))
    
print('END')
```

If you want the sum of 1-n for all numbers remove sum=0 inside while

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot! It worked.  I didn't understand why to remove the sum = 0 from inside the WHILE, I put it inside as on your code and it it worked fine. I could keep entering numbers and make it sum from 1 to N and to print the result as needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
num = int(input('N: '))
sum_ = 0
while True:
   if num < 0:
       num = int(input('ERROR - N: '))
   elif num == 0:
       break
   else:
       sum_ = sum_ + num
       print('Sum: ', sum_) 
       num = int(input('N: '))
```